# User login and logout in Dynamodb

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

The requirement is to store employees login and logout information in DynamoDB.
If an employee works for more than 4 hours a day (it might be at a stretch or with breaks in between) need to notify the employee to log off for that day and take a break. Since I need to poll DB to check if 4 hours is completed for a day or no and for this I don't want to use DB scan approach. This is how my DDb looks, but in order to poll every 10 minutes, since I can't make use of scan. How can I achieve it? Any suggestions are helpful.

| Employee Number | Event DateTime | Action | Worked hours |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| abc | 24/6/2022 9AM | Login | 0 |
| abc | 24/6/2022 12PM | Logout | 3 |
| abc | 24/6/2022 2PM | Login | 3 |

Comment: Please include the design you already have for the database and state the problem you have with it.  Asking someone to show you how to do it, usually gets a down vote. You need to do your research and your part first.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you set the empId as a parition key and create a global secondary index including status and status update date

Primary Index:

- Partition key: empId

Global Secondary Index:

- Partition key: status ('loggedOut' or 'loggedIn')
- Sort Key: statusUpdateDate (epochTime in seconds)

Run a cron job in eventbridge to trigger lambda every 5 min

In the lambda function run the following query to find the employees that are loggedIn for more than 4 hours by the following query:

```
ddbClient.query({
    TableName: 'tableName',
    IndexName: "gsiName",
    KeyConditionExpression: "status = :loggedIn and statusUpdateDate < :currentTimeMinus4Hours",
    ExpressionAttributeValues: {
       ":loggedIn ": "loggedIn",
       ":currentTimeMinus4Hours": moment().utc().unix() - 14400, // now - 4 hours
    },
})
```

Comment: thank you for providing the design. Since I have to deal with millions of employees data, is there some better way to query DynamoDb instead of using status = :loggedIn ?